# Contenedor Docker de React no abre en puerto

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Cree una aplicación de react y ahora necesito dockerizarla. Cree mi dockerfile y el docker-compose.yml, y cuando creo la imagen y ejecuto docker compose up, y aparece el resultado de que la aplicación está corriendo en el localhost:5173, pero cuando abro mi navegador con la url y el puerto que definí en mis archivos, no aparece nada, solo un error de conexión. Aquí está mi dockerfile y mi docker-compose.yml

Dockerfile:

```
# Utiliza una imagen de Node.js como base
FROM node:20.2.0-alpine

# Establece el directorio de trabajo en /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copia el archivo package.json y package-lock.json al contenedor
COPY package*.json ./

# Instala las dependencias de la aplicación
RUN npm install

# Copia el resto de los archivos de la aplicación al contenedor
COPY . .

# Construye la aplicación React
RUN npm run build

# Expone el puerto 5173 para que la aplicación sea accesible desde el exterior
EXPOSE 5173

# Inicia la aplicación cuando se inicie el contenedor
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

Mi docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    image: fpbr-client-docker-image
    ports:
      - "5173:5173"
```

Y cuando ejecuto docker compose up -d, y luego docker ps, me sale el siguiente resultado:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                    PORTS                                       NAMES
68e5fa7db392   fpbr-client-docker-image   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   37 minutes ago   Up 4 seconds              0.0.0.0:5173->5173/tcp, :::5173->5173/tcp   fpbr-client-app-1
```

No abre la aplicación cuando me meto en localhost:5173

Comment: Tu contenedor lo estás ejecutando en local o desde un servidor? Tu docker desktop está ejecutandose, en caso de que sea local

Comment: Estoy usando docker engine en ubuntu. Lo estoy ejecutando en local

Comment: Díaz si lo estás ejecutando en un VPs o servidor, entonces sería la IP de tu servidor no localhost

Comment: Seguro que quieres exponer el puerto 5173? y no el de http o https?